# SQL Calculating Average Time

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to calculate the average time between orders for each customers in SQL. However, I am having issues as I am not able to use LAG() on an aggregate function. How can I fix this issue?

This is the code I have so far which doesn't work. The orders table contain the date the order was placed.

```sql
SELECT customer.customerid, AVG(DATEDIFF(orders.orderdate, 
  LAG(orders.orderdate) OVER (
    PARTITION BY orders.customerid ORDER BY orders.orderdate))
  ) AS avg_time_between_orders
FROM customer
JOIN orders ON customer.customerid = orders.customerid
GROUP BY customerid;
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your table in text format?

Comment: Customer Table have the following columns( customerid, customername, customeraddress) The orders table have the following columns(orderid, customerid, orderdate)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try *splitting* initial query into *two* (first for `Lag` second for aggregation) and combine them with *CTE*:

```
with data as (
  select customer.customerid,  
         orders.orderdate,
         Lag(orders.orderdate) 
           over (partition by orders.customerid 
                     order by orders.orderdate) as PriorOrderDate
    from customer join
         orders on customer.customerid = orders.customerid)

  select customerid,
         Avg(DateDiff(orderdate, PriorOrderDate)) as avg_time_between_orders
    from data
group by customerid;
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I have tried splitting the queries but I get an error saying that I have an invalid identifier in DATEDIFF which I assume is, PriorOrderDate.

Comment: copy the code 1 to 1 all columnames in the cte are available in the outer query, but you can edit your question and add the new code you have#

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using a *subquery* - i.e. creating one query which is nested under another.

```
select customerid, avg(time_between_orders) from (select t1.orderdate as 
date, t1.orderdate - lag(t1.orderdate) over (order by t1.orderdate) as 
time_between_orders, t2.customerid as customerid from orders as t1 inner join 
customer as t2 on t1.customerid=t2.customerid) as subquery group by 
customerid;
```

To explain this query step-by-step:

1. The ultimate aim of this query is to calculate the average time between orders for each customer id. As such, `select customerid, avg(time_between_orders)` is defined at the beginning of the query.
2. However, since we do not have a table with the time between orders, this must be calculated using a separate query.
3. As such, the nested query of `select t1.orderdate as date, t1.orderdate - lag(t1.orderdate) over (order by t1.orderdate) as time_between_orders, t2.customerid as customerid from orders as t1 inner join customer as t2 on t1.customerid=t2.customerid` is used.
4. t1 is defined as the orders table and t2 is defined as the customer table. The time between orders is calculated using a window function as above. The two tables are joined together on the basis of customerid, which then allows for the average time between orders to be calculated on the basis of id.

Comment: that is teh same as the WITH CTE, only another notation